# C++ ensuring a float size of 4 bytes

Tags: c++, floating-point, cross-platform, size, consistency

I need a cross-architecture way to ensure that a float will be 4 bytes (as is on 32-bit windows). For instance, in the structs I'm creating, I'm using `__int32` instead of `int` to ensure an integer value that is 4 bytes long.

How could I do this with a float? I know that I can just substitute the value with an `__int32` type; however, when casting to a float on 64-bit systems, won't I have issues?

Comment: The standard doesn't even guarantee that a 4-byte `float` exists. However I'd imagine that it'd be extremely difficult to find an architecture where `sizeof(float) != sizeof(int32_t)`.

Comment: I have bad news: `__int32` is not cross-platform.

Comment: *Aside*: `__int32` isn't guaranteed to exist on every (or any) system. Try `int32_t` instead.

Comment: You're creating problems for yourself by doing this.  Endian issues are in your future...

Comment: @JimR - Endianness is taken care of for this specific problem.

Comment: @Robᵩ  - Thanks for the tip, didn't realize this. I will make the conversions!

Comment: If you need a specific size you might store things as fixed point and convert to the native floating point format as needed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: @Mysticial - What about on 64-bit windows architectures?

Comment: The only systems I can think of that don't follow IEEE 754 at least to some degree are those that don't have any FP units to begin with, in which case you're dependent on software emulation, which will probably follow IEEE 754 (what else? IBM's standard? ;) )

Comment: @Di-0xide, every arch and every compiler I know of uses 4-byte single precision floats because it's a standard `IEEE 754`

Comment: @Di-0xide There's no difference. The standard says nothing about 32-bit, 64-bit, XX-bit.

Comment: @Di-0xide Fixed point is not difficult.  There are numerous guides that you could research on how to do it.  Since I don't know your requirements for range and precision I don't know if it would be suitable for you.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). @Di-0xide, can you take a step back and tell us more about what your program does?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - So on most major systems (like I said in the other comment; win32/64 and debian32/64) float is 4 bytes?

Comment: @Robᵩ - Just need to ensure that when compiling on 64bit after designing a struct that uses `float` on 32bit, the struct size stays the same.

Comment: @Di-0xide - Can you tell us why you need that?

Comment: @Robᵩ - I'm re-designing the server end of a program without being able to edit/recompile/etc. the client. The client is expecting a struct instance of a certain size to be sent over the network, and I was worried that upon compiling on a 64-bit system, the size of `float` would change much like `int` and `short` do on windows when compiling on 32/64 bit architectures.

Comment: @Di-0xide - Thanks for the explanation. You have bigger problems than just the *size* of the float. You now have to worry about the alignment of the float, the endianness of the float, and the internal representation of the float. If you accept that every compiler you care about uses IEEE 754 32-bits floats for the `float` type, then you're halfway home. If you don't accept that, well, then you've got bigger problems than this question addresses.

Comment: @Robᵩ - I'm packing the float to 1 byte alignment (I believe is the correct way to say that..) using `#pragma pack` (which I'm sure *isn't* cross-platform compatible, but for now it works until it reaches that point). Endianness will be taken care of if the need arises; however, knowing the client is guaranteed to be running on windows in 32-bits and the server will be running either on win32/64 or (hopefully) debian 32/64, I think it'll be fine.

Comment: @Voo: Cray, IBM mainframe, and VAX systems all have their own non-IEEE floating-point representations. But most programmers aren't likely to encounter any of these.

Comment: @Keith IBMs do support IEE 754 though (although with some reduced performance). And VAX are pretty much dead by now, although yes I didn't think of them when writing it. Not the slightest idea about crays, except that they're big super computers and that they're still around.

Comment: @Di-0xide: Why exactly do you need 4-byte `float`? Is a 4-byte size your only requirement, or are there other requirements on the representation?

Comment: @Voo: "IBMs" covers a whole heck of a lot of computers. I was thinking of old mainframe systems like the IBM 370, which I'm fairly sure didn't support IEEE floating-point. Probably all their more modern systems do.

Comment: Gentlemen, please take it to chat; it sounds like you're in the middle of a real-time converation. The comments aren't made for that.

Comment: @Mysticial I've seen some 8-bit microcontroller compilers allow an option for choosing between 24-bit float and 32-bit float

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I need a cross-architecture way to ensure that a float will be 4 bytes

There is no analog to `int32_t` for floating-point values.

The only cross-platform way to achieve what you want is to test for it with either runtime or static asserts.

```
#include <cassert>
int main () {
    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    // If control reaches this line, then you've 
    // ensured that float is 4 bytes.


    // rest of your program goes here
}
```

Comment: Right. What did you want it to do if `float` isn't 4 bytes?

Comment: I *need* the float to be 4 bytes.

Comment: A `static_assert` is better, but limits the range of compilers to recent ones.

Comment: Or, more specifically, to be able to convert a 4-byte integer to a float.

Comment: You have the option of doing a `static_assert` to ensure at compile time that the size of float is 4.

Comment: @Di-0xide Well, the standard doesn't guarantee that a 4-byte `float` exists. So what are you going to do if it doesn't? (not saying that this is likely to happen, but if you're after absolute portability...)

Comment: @Di-0xide - you can always convert a 4-byte integer to float: `int32_t i = 0x42; float f = i;`

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - The problem is that if the float is not 4 bytes, then what? I can't compile on that architecture? That doesn't help me.

Comment: Yes, if float is not 4 bytes, then you can't compile on that architecture.

Comment: @Robᵩ - what happens when the native float is not 4 bytes long?

Comment: @Di-0xide Then you're probably working on such an extremely specific platform that your whole floating point code won't work because it relies on lots of assumptions that won't hold.

Comment: See that's what I'm asking - how would I store a 4 byte float, assuming the different architectures will have a float size of *at least* 4 bytes (i.e. assuming there will be no data truncation)

Comment: Di-0xide, unless you're developing for some really off of the wall CPU, it's never, ever, ever going to come up.  If you're really afraid of it, just put in the static assert and deal with it on a case by case basis.

Comment: @Voo - I just need to ensure that a struct using the `float` type will stay the same size on different platforms.

Comment: @Di-0xide lots of typedefs based on `#define`s that the build system sets after detecting the platform.

Comment: @Di-0xide If you're looking for a full-proof and standard compliant way to do this: **It doesn't exist. Period.**

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity - so for instance, `float` is the same size on win32, win64, and linux (debian) 32/64?

Comment: @Mysticial Well assuming there are 32bit integers available, he can certainly emulate IEEE 754 in software - well I hope he doesn't care about performance.

Comment: @Di-0xide I think it'd be an extremely good idea to read up on IEEE-754 (the specific standard), because we're talking about *hardware* support, while you're enumerating operating systems, which have **absolutely** nothing to do with what floats are available (yes not true for AVX and co). Although neither Windows nor debian support any platforms that don't have IEEE 754..

Comment: @Di-0xide, yes.  It is under every compiler I can think of.  Because it's a standard. `IEEE 754.`  The only case where it's going to come up is if someone writes a new compiler for the platform that doesn't respect the `IEEE 754` standard.  And no one's going to do that, because it won't play nice with the `x86` instruction set, which expects floats in that form.  So you're going to need an off of the wall CPU with a non-standard implementation of floating point (which you're not going to see unless you're doing embedded systems, and probably not even then.)

Comment: @Di-0xide: I've used systems that have non-IEEE floating-point hardware (IBM mainframes, VAX, and Cray vector systems). Crays in particular have 64-bit `float`, and *no* 32-bit floating-point type. These systems were designed before the IEEE standard existed; they're probably *why* that standard was invented. You're not likely to run into such systems yourself.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a standard compliant way to do this because floating point data size is tied to the CPU.  The `IEEE-754` standard (which all processors that support floating point use to my knowledge) defines a single-precision floating point value as 4-bytes.

The reason why there isn't a standard mention is because the writers of C don't want to tie themselves to a specific implementation of floating point, in case the standard changes or is updated.  And also because the CPU determines the sizes of and implementation of single and double precision floats anyway, so it's not something that the compiler concern itself with.

If you're worried about it, you can use a `static_assert` to ensure that `sizeof(float) == 4`; however, this isn't a problem you're going to run into I wouldn't imagine.  And if it is you should deal with it on a case-by-case basis (which is really going to be an architecture-by-architecture basis.)

Comment: That makes sense. I'll have to read up more on the IEEE-754 standard (everyone always throws around these standards but I'm still trying to understand what they all are and how they tie into each other).

Comment: If you're still around, you should probably give the accepted answer to Rob-phi.  I just expanded off of his answer.